# Preventing js function to be executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my app there is a table with countries data and it also uses pagination. For each row there is a delete button that triggers a function via ajax and the country is deleted from the database, the row slides up and the table is rendered again depending on the page we're at.

This was my original function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-remove', function(event) {
    var thiz = $(this);
    var id = thiz.next('input:hidden').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/country/' + id,
        type: 'DELETE'
    })
    .done(function() {
        thiz.parent().parent().parent()
            .find('td')
            .wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />')
            .parent()
            .find('td > div')
            .slideUp(200, function() {
                thiz.parent().parent().remove();
                    if (curPage) {
                        if ($('.table > tbody > tr').length > 1) {
                            renderCountries(curPage);
                        } else {
                            var page = getURLParameter(curPage, 'page');
                            if (page !== '1') {
                                prevPage = previousPageURL(curPage, 'page');
                                renderCountries(prevPage);
                                curPage = prevPage;
                            } else {
                                renderCountries();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        renderCountries();
                    }
            });
    });
});
```

However, I found out that the `slideUp()` function was being executed multiple times, which messed up the whole thing, and I didn't know the reason, so I changed it and now I am using `delay()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-remove', function(event) {
    var thiz = $(this);
    var id = thiz.next('input:hidden').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/country/' + id,
        type: 'DELETE'
    })
    .done(function() {
        thiz.parent().parent().parent()
            .find('td')
            .wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />')
            .parent()
            .find('td > div')
            .slideUp(200)
            .delay(200, function() {
                thiz.parent().parent().remove();
                    if (curPage) {
                        if ($('.table > tbody > tr').length > 1) {
                            renderCountries(curPage);
                        } else {
                            var page = getURLParameter(curPage, 'page');
                            if (page !== '1') {
                                prevPage = previousPageURL(curPage, 'page');
                                renderCountries(prevPage);
                                curPage = prevPage;
                            } else {
                                renderCountries();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        renderCountries();
                    }
            });
    });
});
```

However, now the function executed after `delay()` is being executed twice. I don't understand why all this is happening, and I would like to know how can I fix this.

**edit**: HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Continent</th>
            <th>Capital</th>
            <th>Language</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>asdfdsaf</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/country/all" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="pull-right"><input name="_token" value="l2LCeqGRZARM6YUR6hqTgoKWNRRxAUcwspf4kf1v" type="hidden">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove btn btn-xs btn-danger"></span>
                        <input name="id" value="1" type="hidden">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How many divs do you have in td? Maybe it's just executed for each div?

Comment: Use promises http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: um the `div` is just a temporal wrap so the slideUp works.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or something with some markup to test out on?

Comment: I can't use a fiddle because the code works along with the server, but I will update the HTML

Comment: @dabadaba You could give us the *rendered HTML* by viewing the source of the page in your browser

Comment: ok I edited my post with the rendered HTML (just one row)

Comment: What's `curPage`? You never define it anywhere. (Don't let your functions depend on hidden global state.)

Comment: Are you sure your ajax isn't being executed twice?  Can you add a message from the server to ensure that the entry actually was removed from the database and check this before you run you done:function()

Comment: Also, try using .closest('td') rather than .parent().parent().  One small alteration in your DOM and things go haywire very quickly;

Comment: @Tomalak `curPage` is set to `null` and once a pagination link is clicked it is set to the link's href value.

Comment: @Michael I just tested how many times the `delete` method is being executed and it's just once, it's just the function attached to `delay()` the one being executed twice.

Comment: Can you add var index = 0; as the first line of the done:function() and then and then check if index==0 as the first line of the slideUp:function() and add index++; as the last line of the slideUp:function()?  Basically, without a fiddle, it is difficult to troubleshoot, I'm just trying to find a way to MacGyver this

Comment: @Michael there is no `slideUp()` function, do you mean the one attached to `delay()`? anyway, what do you want to know by doing that? knowing how many times the function is being executed?

Comment: @Michael well actually your `index` idea suggested me a way to prevent the bad things happening due to the function being executed more than once, I am setting a boolean value to `false` in `done()` and changing it's value to true in the `delay()` function, whose body is now wrapped in an `if` statement checking the value of that boolean. However, this is not preventing the function from being executed twice, it's just an ugly patch :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58179/discussion-between-michael-and-dabadaba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm removing a bunch of extra code, but this is my suggestion:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/country/' + id,
    type: 'DELETE'
})
.done(function() {
    var first = true;
    thiz.parent().parent().parent()
        .find('td')
        .wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />')
        .parent()
        .find('td > div')
        .slideUp(200)
        .delay(200, function() {
            if (first==true){
                first=false;
                thiz.parent().parent().remove();
                if (curPage) {
                    if ($('.table > tbody > tr').length > 1) {
                        renderCountries(curPage);
                    } else {
                        var page = getURLParameter(curPage, 'page');
                        if (page !== '1') {
                            prevPage = previousPageURL(curPage, 'page');
                            renderCountries(prevPage);
                            curPage = prevPage;
                        } else {
                            renderCountries();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    renderCountries();
                }
           }
        });
});
```

Doesn't fix the issue of firing twice, only executes *your* part of the code once.

Comment: that is exactly what I did to fix my problem, thanks to your suggestion in the comments, which gave me the idea. However this is just a patch: as you say, it doesn't prevent the function from begin executed twice, which is the weird part of this issue I'd like to put a solution to.

Comment: I agree with this solution, even if you fix the problem of it firing twice, you can't stop the user from double clicking.